# Show sidebar when acessing a doc that is not listed in sidebars.json (docusaurus)

Tags: docusaurus

I noticed that when I access a doc that is not inside sidebars.json, the left sidebar doesn't shows up, but if I add this doc do the JSON is shows, I want the left sidebar to be visible, even id the doc that I'm accessing is
not listed in this JSON file

[left container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXtSc.png)

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your question. Could you provide a link to a GitHub repo?

Comment: I mean when a doc (a md file) isn't listed in sidebars.json file (website/sidebars.json) it doesn't show the left "docsNavContainer" as the image indicates